# tikzposter / authblk - how to change index font size of the affiliations

Tags: titles, tikzposter, authblk

[image: From my MWE]

I used tikzposter to create a poster and authblk to do my affiliations. My problem is that the first index of the affiliations ( index 1, at Dept. of Alpha Research in the MWE) is a lot larger than the font of the rest of the affiliations. How can I standardize it or fix the font size of my affiliations?

here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[25pt]{tikzposter}
\usepackage{authblk} %Allows improved author and affiliation design
\usetheme{Desert}

%Set title authors and institute
\title{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering ULTRA LONG TITLE NO ONE BOTHERS   TO    READ}}
\institute{Alpha University}

\author[1,2]{John Doe}
\author[2]{Jane Doe}
\author[2]{Jennifer Doe}
\author[3,4]{James Doe}
\author[3]{Jenna Smith}
\author[2]{John Smith}
\author[1]{Jennifer Smith}


\affil[1]{\normalsize Dept. of Alpha Research}
\affil[2]{\normalsize Beta corporation}
\affil[3]{\normalsize Gamma university}
\affil[4]{\normalsize Delta Research group}

%Make title customizer
\makeatletter
\def\maketitle{\AB@maketitle}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\block{Abstract}{
Tih is an abstract to fill the MWE
} % See Section 4.2
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\renewcommand\Affilfont{\small\color{orange!80!black}}` to set the font of the affiliation block.

[image: philyeardmanTikzposterAuthblk]