# How can I keep multiple authblk affiliation in tikzposter in one line?

Tags: tikzposter, authblk

I came across [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294600/tikzposter-authblk-how-to-change-index-font-size-of-the-affiliations) that shows how to use affiliations in `tikzposter` using `authblk` package.

I would like to do something similar, but having several institutions with relatively short names - I would like to save space on the top of the poster and keep them in one line.

How can that be achieved?

Comment: Some code would be nice. We have no idea how you have adapted the code in the example.

Comment: I used the code 'asis' from the question & answer I linked to. Should I repost it here?

Comment: Always a good idea

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the following lines after loading the package `authblk`.

```
\usepackage{authblk} % improved author and affiliation design
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\maketitle{\AB@maketitle} % revert \maketitle to its old definition
\renewcommand\AB@affilsepx{\quad\protect\Affilfont} % put affiliations into one line
\makeatother
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\Large} % set font for affiliations
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[25pt]{tikzposter}
\usepackage{authblk} % improved author and affiliation design
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\maketitle{\AB@maketitle} % revert \maketitle to its old definition
\renewcommand\AB@affilsepx{\quad\protect\Affilfont} % put affiliations into one line
\makeatother
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\Large} % set font for affiliations

\usetheme{Desert}

%Set title authors and institute
\title{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering ULTRA LONG TITLE NO ONE BOTHERS   TO    READ}}
\institute{Alpha University}

\author[1,2]{John Doe}
\author[2]{Jane Doe}
\author[2]{Jennifer Doe}
\author[3,4]{James Doe}
\author[3]{Jenna Smith}
\author[2]{John Smith}
\author[1]{Jennifer Smith}

\affil[1]{Dept. of Alpha Research}
\affil[2]{Beta corporation}
\affil[3]{Gamma university}
\affil[4]{Delta Research group}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\block{Abstract}%
  {This is an abstract to fill the MWE.}
\end{document}
```